# how can I fix this runtime error when doing crc checking python 3 scd-30 co2 Sensor

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, runtime-error, crc, pi

How could I fix this runtime error?
I'd like it to skip the reading and carry on with the program if it gets an error but it stops the program

I've got the Adafruit SCD-30 Co2 sensor and when reading the data using their example code I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pm.py", line 43, in <module>
print("CO2:", scd.CO2, "PPM")
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/adafruit_scd30.py", line 183, in CO2
self._read_data()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/adafruit_scd30.py", line 246, in _read_data
raise RuntimeError("CRC check failed while reading data")
RuntimeError: CRC check failed while reading data
```

This is the line it fails on

```
    print("CO2:", scd.CO2, "PPM")
```

This is the crc checking section of their code

```
    def _read_data(self):
    self._send_command(_CMD_READ_MEASUREMENT)
    with self.i2c_device as i2c:
        i2c.readinto(self._buffer)

    crcs_good = True

    for i in range(0, 18, 3):
        crc_good = self._check_crc(self._buffer[i : i + 2], self._buffer[i + 2])
        if crc_good:
            continue
        crcs_good = False
    if not crcs_good:
        raise RuntimeError("CRC check failed while reading data")

    self._co2 = unpack(">f", self._buffer[0:2] + self._buffer[3:5])[0]
    self._temperature = unpack(">f", self._buffer[6:8] + self._buffer[9:11])[0]
    self._relative_humidity = unpack(
        ">f", self._buffer[12:14] + self._buffer[15:17]
    )[0]
```

Is there a way to tell it to do something like this

```
    if not crcs_good:
        skip reading and wait for the next one
```

Comment: have you looked at the ty, except pattern?

Comment: yes, it still does it.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue. I finally figured out that I needed to slow down my clock speed on my I2C on my raspberry pi. Not sure if you are using a pi as well but here's a link to a good write up on how to do it https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-on-raspberrypi-linux/i2c-clock-stretching . I am running the sensor at 10khz or 10000hz and haven't had a crc error crash my code since.

Comment: Your terminology looks spot on here, this slows down the i2c clock speed which is effectively a workaround and one that is not guaranteed to be perfect.

The [Sensirion datasheet](https://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/9.5_CO2/Sensirion_CO2_Sensors_SCD30_Interface_Description.pdf) states: "Maximal I2C speed is 100kHz and the master has to support clock stretching. Sensirion recommends to operate the SCD30 at a baud rate of 50 kHz or smaller." The 50kHz comments is a bit weird really, it either works at 100kHz (i2c standard mode speed) or it doesn't.

Comment: This could also be partly related to an omission in the Adafruit CircuitPython library mentioned in [GitHub:  adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_SCD30:  Datasheet mentions 3ms delays in i2c communication #13](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_SCD30/issues/13).

Comment: There's a discussion on Raspberry Pi 4 i2c capabilities on [Raspberry Pi 4 Forum: I2C clock stretching support in Raspberry Pi 4 (BCM2711)?](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=302381).

I just put in [Does the Raspberry Pi support the i2c clock stretching feature?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/127271/does-the-raspberry-pi-support-the-i2c-clock-stretching-feature) as it would be nice to have a definitive, detailed description and answer to the hardware and software options to deal with enabling this feature.